# upload file to Skydrive on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, onedrive

This is for Windows Phone 7.1. Currently this is my code.

```
private async void UploadFile(IsolatedStorageFile myFile)
{
    if ( App.ConnectClient != null )
    {
        App.ConnectClient.BackgroundUploadAsync("me/skydrive",
                                                          new Uri("/shared/transfers/" + testFileName, UriKind.Relative),
                                                          OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
    }
}
```

It runs without giving an error but when I check skydrive, the file is not there.

If needed, this is my file creation code

```
private IsolatedStorageFile WriteCSV()
{
    IsolatedStorageFile myStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    testFileName = "sample.csv";

    using ( StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(testFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, myStorage)) )
    {
        writeFile.WriteLine("some data");
        writeFile.Close();
    }

    return myStorage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you created a file, it wasn't created in /shared/transfers location but in root - "/"

So this should work better:

```
if ( App.ConnectClient != null )
    {
        App.ConnectClient.GetCompleted += ConnectClient_GetCompleted;
        App.ConnectClient.BackgroundUploadAsync("me/skydrive",
                                                new Uri("/" + testFileName, UriKind.Relative),
                                                OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
    }
```

Comment: shared/transfers is the root directory for IsolatedStorage

Comment: I have ran your sample and checked the isolated storage after that. This is what it looks like [link](http://igrali.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/storage.jpg)

Comment: Your suggestion gives the error `Input parameter 'uploadLocation' is invalid. 'uploadLocation' must be rooted in \shared\transfers.` Look like I have to create or move the file in that directory. How would I do that?

Comment: I got the file to be in /shared/transfers but the file still isn't uploaded to skydrive